# insertion sort algorithm in objective c application crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

i am trying to implement the insertion sort algorithm using Obj-c i converted the commented lines below from C into Obj C , (hope they are correct if anybody can have a look and assist) but the application crashes with the following error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'

```
-(IBAction)clicked_insertsort:(id)sender{

    NSMutableArray  *iarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:garr];
    int n = [iarray count]  ;
    NSLog(@"%@",iarray);

    int i,j,x,k;

     for(i=1;i<=n-1;i++)  

     {  
     j=i;  

     //x=a[i]; 
    x=[[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i]intValue];    

     //while(a[j-1]>x && j>0)  
     while ([[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j-1]intValue] >x && j>0)


     {  

     //a[j]=a[j-1];
    [iarray replaceObjectAtIndex: (j) withObject: [iarray objectAtIndex: (j-1)]];
     j=j-1;  
     }  

    // a[j]=x;  
    [[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j]intValue] == x; 

     }
    NSLog(@"%@",iarray);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid casting your indexes to unsigned int. try it one at a time and which ever one changes the error to say -1 rather than 4294967295 is the index you are having a problem with

When j gets set to 0 you're now going to be indexing into iarray at index -1, which when casted to an unsigned int is equal to 4294967295

Comment: its in your while loop, change the order to be while(j>0 && [[iarray objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)j-1]intValue] >x)

Comment: you are correct no crash thanks can u kindly help me why it is not sorting here is the result array before and after [Session started at 2012-09-12 02:13:43 +0300.]
2012-09-12 02:13:49.127 sort_alg[1748:207] (
    43,
    18,
    15,
    135,
    37,
    81,
    157,
    166,
    117,
    110
)
2012-09-12 02:13:49.130 sort_alg[1748:207] (
    43,
    43,
    43,
    43,
    135,
    135,
    135,
    135,
    157,
    166
)

Comment: am i doing anything wrong with the transfer of arrays from c to obj c thanks a lot

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation for the sort functions built into NSMutableArray. if you are still having trouble, try searching on here for the function you want to use, or ask a new question if you cant find one already.

Dont forget to accept this answer for other people who are having a similar issue